# `variable` was mutably borrowed here in the previous iteration of the loop

Tags: rust, pcap

I'm fairly new to Rust, and I've been trying to work through an error in my code.

The code below compiles.  **However**, if I uncomment out the line to add a packet to my buffer, it throws the error:

```
`interface` was mutably borrowed here in the previous iteration of the loop
```

How?  It's not related at all to the packet at that point.  I thought I was beginning to grasp references and memory management concepts, but this has me second guessing everything...

```rust
        let mut buffer: VecDeque<pcap::Packet> = VecDeque::with_capacity(1000);
        while let Ok(packet) = interface.next_packet() {
            if start_time.is_none() {
                start_time = Some(Instant::now());
            }

            let buf_packet = packet.to_owned();

            // buffer.push_back(buf_packet);

            let elapsed = start_time.unwrap().elapsed();
            if elapsed >= time_limit {
                break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and provide a [mre] this snippet of code is not something we can help you debug. It might be a limitation of the current borrow checker.

Comment: Looks like a [`pcap::Packet`](https://docs.rs/pcap/latest/pcap/struct.Packet.html) has a lifetime associated with it. So `.to_owned()` wouldn't decouple it from the original source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Packet`](https://docs.rs/pcap/latest/pcap/struct.Packet.html) has no owned variant. `to_owned()` is from the [blanket `ToOwned` implementation in the standard library](https://docs.rs/pcap/latest/pcap/struct.Packet.html#impl-ToOwned-for-Packet%3C%27a%3E), which is implemented for anything that implements `Clone`.  Weirdly, this type implements `Clone` but not `Copy`.

Anyway, `Packet` just holds two references.  Cloning copies those references, so this doesn't actually do anything meaningful with regards to the borrows or their lifetimes.

Instead, consider implementing your own "owned packet" type that owns its own data:

```
struct OwnedPacket {
    pub header: PacketHeader,
    pub data: Vec<u8>,
}

impl<'a> From<Packet<'a>> for OwnedPacket {
    fn from(other: Packet<'a>) -> Self {
        Self {
            header: *other.header,
            data: other.data.into(),
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can change your deque to `VecDeque<OwnedPacket>` and call `packet.into()` when pushing the packet to perform the copy.

Comment: Thank you for a comprehensive and explanatory answer.   The thought of lifetimes never crossed my mind.  I've also not used the .into() function before, so that's been a fun read -- I can learn a lot from that aspect.  Thanks again for a quick and quality answer.